# Rationale behind revocation of ssh certificates

Tags: openssh

Lets say that I have a file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
with `RevokedKeys /etc/ssh/keys/cert.list`

What does revoke when I add a ssh certificate (not the public key) to `/etc/ssh/keys/cert.list`?
I've found that what is really revoked is the public key which is based that certificate.

I mean, if I issue a new certificate with the same public key, I cannot login using the new certificate.

So, is true that what is revoked is the underlying public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on what you list**

As listed on [ssh-keygen(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html):

> The files may either contain a KRL specification (see
> below) or public keys, listed one per line.  Plain public keys are revoked by listing their
> hash or contents in the KRL and certificates revoked by serial number or key ID (if the
> serial is zero or not available).

So, you can revoke either a key or a certficate.

If a key was compromised (or weak to begin with, see the [Debian ssh keys fiasco](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2008/msg00152.html)), you wouldn't want a new certificate to use that same key.

Comment: Does an ssh certificate contains the public key? Because I included the certificate in the revokation file not the public key...

Comment: The certificate obviously contains a copy of the public key (plus some metadata).

Comment: Yup, I've found that `-z` option is very important when you create a certificate, because you can use the serial later to revoke specifically only one certificate.

Comment: An easy way to generate uniqueness is to add `-z $(date -u "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` to your `ssh-keygen` command.  This will make the serial number the current timestamp. As long as you are not generating many keys per second, you should be fine with this.